# How to select one value from multiple columns?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I need to intelligently combine the values of three columns in a dataframe like the one below. The code needs to select the first type prediction that is `True`, only the first even if another subsequent prediction is also `True`. If none of the predictions are `True`, the value returned should be `NaN`.

```
index    name       t1        t1_check  t2       t2_check  t3       t3_check
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        cow        animal    True      phone    False     fruit    False
1        apple      animal    False     fruit    True      food     True
2        carrot     vehicle   False     veg      True      animal   False
3        dog        pet       True      animal   True      object   False
4        horse      window    False     object   False     animal   True
5        car        pet       False     food     False     fruit    False
```

Here`s what I tried:

First I combined the two related columns and dropped the old ones.

```
In:
df['t1_comb'] = str(df['t1']) + str(df['t1_check'])
df['t2_comb'] = str(df['t2']) + str(df['t2_check'])
df['t3_comb'] = str(df['t3']) + str(df['t3_check'])

df.drop(columns=['t1', 't1_check', 't2', 't2_check', 't3', 't3_check'], inplace=True)

Out:
index    name       t1_comb         t2_comb        t3_comb
---------------------------------------------------------------
0        cow        animalTrue      phoneFalse     fruitFalse
1        apple      animalFalse     fruitTrue      foodTrue
2        carrot     vehicleFalse    vegTrue        animalFalse
3        dog        petTrue         animalTrue     objectFalse
4        horse      windowFalse     objectFalse    animalTrue
5        car        petFalse        foodFalse      fruitFalse
```

Then I tried replaces all the entries that contain `False` with `NaN` and remove the `True` string from each entry.

```
In:
df.loc[df['t1_comb'].str.contains('False'), 't1_comb'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['t2_comb'].str.contains('False'), 't2_comb'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['t3_comb'].str.contains('False'), 't3_comb'] = np.nan

df.t1_comb = df.t1_comb.str.replace('True', '')
df.t2_comb = df.t2_comb.str.replace('True', '')
df.t3_comb = df.t3_comb.str.replace('True', '')

Out:
index    name       t1_comb         t2_comb        t3_comb
---------------------------------------------------------------
0        cow        animal          NaN            NaN
1        apple      NaN             fruit          food
2        carrot     NaN             veg            NaN
3        dog        pet             animal         NaN
4        horse      NaN             NaN            animal
5        car        NaN             NaN            NaN
```

The next step is where I'm having some difficulties, the part where only the first value is considered.

The result I need should look something like this:

```
index    name       type
----------------------------
0        cow        animal
1        apple      fruit
2        carrot     veg
3        dog        pet
4        horse      animal
5        car        NaN
```

Comment: What have you tried? To me, a `lambda` could also be used here

Comment: @mad_ I added more information about what I tried. About the ```lambda```, I'm not sure how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure a better solution is possible but you can use `apply` for each row

```
def myfunc(row):
    if row['t1_check']:
        return row['t1']
    elif row['t2_check']:
        return row['t2']
    elif row['t3_check']:
        return row['t3']
    return np.nan

df['type']=df.apply(myfunc,axis=1)
df[['name','type']]
```

Output

```
index    name       type
----------------------------
0        cow        animal
1        apple      fruit
2        carrot     veg
3        dog        pet
4        horse      animal
5        car        NaN
```